# How to disable login in Spring Boot Netflix' eureka?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm setting up a microservice architecture using Spring Boot and Eureka. I followed several tutorials. However, the Eureka server is showing a login when trying to open the dashboard. Also, registration of a client fails (I think because of the enabled security).

**How can I disable the security?**

This is my configuration:

```
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
eureka.environment=dev

server.port=1112
```

I'm using a .properties file instead of .yml. What I tried is to add the property

```
security.basic.enabled=false
```

but the result was the same. So I tried to configure Spring Boot Security by myself but this caused 404 HTTP errors because the '/login'-controller was not found (and I don't want to develop this at the moment).

Comment: You must have some security configured, due to which it is asking for username and password.
Can u post your project on github? A minimal, verifiable sample.

Comment: @IndraneelBende Here's the link to github: https://github.com/ericfischerbav/Lia-Eureka

Comment: You have added two starter security dependencies in your Gradle. Why u need that?

Comment: those dependencies are configuring basic username password security and that is why you cannot register your application with eureka server.

Comment: Getting now a 404... But this solved the security problem. Thanks for your help! If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Have u given the right IP address in your eureka client application?

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/

Comment: Look at the above guide and follow it. Let me know if u have any questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added two starter security dependencies in your Gradle. Those are configuring basic username password security. Please remove them.

Answer (score 0):

you can also exclude the **SecurityAutoConfiguration** in your spring application main class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```